# Free all the space allocated for a pointer-to-pointer, without knowing its type

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have a C program which uses a few pointers such as `int **`, `float **`, `double **`, `long **`, etc.  At the end, I want to free the space that was allocated for them.

To modularize things, I have a function that can take an object of the form *pointer-to-pointer* and free the memory space allocated for it. For instance, the following, for a variable of type `int **`.

```
void FreeIntArray(int **A, int length){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i ++)
       free(A[i]);
    free(A);
}
```

However, to free a variable of the form `float **` or `double **`, I need to write another function that is almost a carbon copy of the one above, except changing `int **` to `float **` in the function definition.

Is a way to design a single function that can free space allocated to any of the following datatypes: `int **`, `float **`, `double **`, `long **` ?

Comment: The problem here is that you are treating the data as an array of arrays (more precisely an array of pointers to other arrays, all dynamically allocated), and this is what makes it impossible to write a generic function. The only solution I can see is to use preprocessor macros instead (which I really don't like recommending).

Comment: "Free a pointer" - You likely don't want to `free` the pointer, but the object **it points to**

Comment: @Olaf: Presumably "freeing a pointer" means passing a pointer value to `free()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Using the correct terms - and being aware of them often can self-answer such questions.

Comment: What for do you use those double-pointers? If that is for some 2D indexing, use a 2D array and simply `free(array);` it.

Comment: @Olaf it might be a jagged array rather than a straight-forward 2-d array.

Comment: @JohnColeman It's precisely that. The object A is not exactly a matrix since every A[i] is a pointer of different size.

Comment: @Olaf: 2D arrays are much less flexible. (BTW, I suggest avoiding the phrase "double pointer"; that would be a `double*`. "Pointer to pointer" is more accurate.)

Comment: @JohnColeman: That's why I had this part: "If that is for some 2D indexing" in my comment!

Comment: @KeithThompson: Read my comment above. Of course there applications for both. But as a long-term user here you well know how many posters use `**` pointers just because they don't know what a 2D array is, resp. how to declare them (and their teachers often also have no idea). A 2D array is fine unless you really need different lengths per entry (there might be advantages if the inner dimension can change, but that depends how clever memory allocation is).

Comment: @Olaf: How often, in real-world programs, do you need a 2D array with dimensions that have known fixed values when you write the program? How useful is an image manipulation program that can only handle a single fixed image size? Sure, it can happen, but that's not what the question is about. If someone asked about dealing with an integer variable, I wouldn't ask why they need a variable and suggest using a constant instead.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Are you aware the dimensions can be variables? Are you aware of VLAs? There is absolutely no problem with e.g. `int i = 5, j = 6, (*a)[i] = malloc(sizeof(*a) * j);`.

Comment: I wrote up a solution that wouldn't depend on pointer representation or size -- and then I realized I was making assumptions about pointer representation and size. You have an array of `some_type*` in memory, and you need to convert each element (explicitly or implicitly) to `void*` so you can pass it to `free()`. There is no way to do that without knowing *at compile time* exactly what `some_type` is. The best you could do is pass a pointer to a wrapper function for `free()`, but that doesn't help much; you'd still have to define a wrapper for each type.

Comment: @Olaf: Are you aware that VLAs are an optional feature in C11?

Comment: @KeithThompson: They were mandatory in C99. It was a very bad decission and completely off the commitees's normal practice of maintaining compatibility. But then: which modern C11 compiler do you know which does not support VLAs, too?

Comment: @Olaf: No, but this is off-topic for this question anyway.

Comment: Not without passing a custom free function to the function.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to punctiliously adhere to the ISO C standard's definition of what is maximally portable, there is no way to do this without repetitive coding. We can roll the logic into a single function, but that function will need some sort of switch on an integer variable indicating the type, so it can access the `type **` pointer correctly as the correct type.

We can drop maximal portability and just assume that all pointers have the same representation. (Plus the additional assumption that we won't be bitten by strict aliasing assumptions in the optimizing compiler.) Then we can write it like this:

```
void free_array(void *aptr, size_t nelem) {
    void **a = (void **) aptr;
    while (nelem--)
      free(*a++);
    free(aptr);
}
```

Another alternative is to use a macro:

```
#define GEN_AFREE(name, type)                   \
   void afree_ ## name (type **a, size_t nelem) \
   {                                            \
     [...]                                      \
   }

GEN_FREE_ARRAY_FUN(int, int)
GEN_FREE_ARRAY_FUN(double, double)
GEN_FREE_ARRAY_FUN(string, char)
```

Or instead of a defining macro, we could just make a macro that encapsulates looping over an array and calling free:

```
#define FREE_ARRAY(array, size) do {         \
  size_t iNdEx;                              \
  for (iNdEx = 0; iNdEx < (size); iNdEx++)   \
    free((array)[iNdEx]);                    \
  free(array);                               \
} while (0)
```

Comment: Minor: suggest `int iNdEx;` --> `size_t iNdEx;`

Comment: After this line: `void **a = (void **) aptr;` if pointer aptr doesn't alias a pointer to a pointer to void, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @2501 This is why the answer refers to this as not maximally portable; that is what the text *"additional assumption that we won't be bitten by strict aliasing assumptions in the optimizing compiler"* refers to.

Comment: How do you determine whether you 'were bitten'? It is impossible. You cannot reason like that with undefined behavior. Your answer hints as if the program is just less portable or something like that, when in reality it is completely broken.

Comment: @2501 Without a demonstrated failing test case (supported platform, compiler and its invocation, on a surrounding complete driver program with a `main`) that is only a uselessly austere academic opinion which doesn't add anything to the existing acknowledgement of the code's ISO C status. ("Supported platform" means: anything which has same-sized pointers of all types with the same bitwise representation.)

Comment: @2501 How you we determine that we weren't bitten? For example, we can conduct a code review of the generated machine code. Firstly, to be on the safe side, I'd put that function into its own translation unit, and ensure there are no whole program optimizations used. I'd check that, by golly, the compiled function really is marching through the array, and passing each pointer word to an external call to the `free` function. Then I'd look at the calls to the function, to see that they are passing in the arrays properly, and that all pointers have been committed to the arrays prior to the call.

Comment: @2501 A complementary approach would be to research the documentation for the supported compilers regarding how they deal with such aliasing cases: which formally undefined aliasing cases are actual threats to correctness and which are benign, and what code generation options influence this and how.

Comment: @2501 Then of course there is testing, including testing with tools. If a malloc debugging tool reports no leaks at the end of the program, it gives us confidence that the free loop marched through the right pointers. A tool like Valgrind can give us confidence that no memory is being misused. Then we of course have functional tests for the program's specified behaviors.

Comment: UB is real and it happens. Cases where such code ('generic' void**) failed after years of working just fine, exist. The correct way of fixing undefined behavior is at it source (no pun intended), which is the source code. Any other approach doomed at the start, and worse, retains undefined behavior. Ok let's say you did all of the things you mention (including checking the (entire?) generated binary, which is ridiculous, but fine). The undefined behavior is still there. At any new release of the compiler may break the code. Any new hardware may break the code.

Comment: @2501 > *UB is real and it happens*.  I completely agree; for instance, UB happens every time the program relies on a documented language extension. (This isn't necessarily one, but *can* be with features like GCC's `-fno-strict-aliasing`)

Comment: No. UB does not happen everytime an extension is used. Read the third paragraph: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99741

Comment: @2501 You're confusing the normative term *undefined behavior* from ISO C (as I am using it) which refers to the absence of a requirement in that document, with "behavior not defined by anyone at all". (Thus if the compiler produces a predictable, documented dialog box where you can click OK to accept a value of zero when a division by zero occurs, it is no longer undefined because someone somewhere defined it. However, **ISO C** still doesn't define it; it makes no mention of such a dialog box.)

Comment: @2501 You can't be a proper ISO C pedant, if your definition of *undefined behavior* is that loose! If *defined* means "by anyone at all", then if I get the correct machine language that I wanted, it's defined! The compiler writer defined it, through their choice of code generating strategy. There is no leg to stand on to call it "completely broken".  It can only be "completely broken" if we regard *ISO C defined* behavior as the be-all and end-all of program correctness (not any other defined behavior).

Comment: @Kaz: A fundamental problem with the Standard and UB is that the Standard offers no guidance about what should be expected in cases where an implementation describes the behavior of some actions in more detail than required by the Standard, but the Standard categorizes an overlapping category of actions as invoking UB.  Compiler writers used to view if as so blindingly obvious that implementation that describe a behavior should generally behave as described even if the Standard says they aren't required to define the behavior, that they seldom bothered to explicitly say that.